Unable to repackage project with QFieldSync
I have a QGIS-project, that I packaged with QFieldSync to use it with QField.
In many cases I directly access my PostGis-Database to collect data in the field, so that I don't have to sync data back to the database via QFieldSync.
The only problem I encounter is when I make changes to my desktop QGIS-Project (adding an additional layer or changing symbology). At this point I'm unable to package this project again with QFieldSync, since QFieldSync does not offer this possibility. Even when I save the project under a new name and an other path it's not posible to export this project a second time.
Is there a way to get the project back in a state that could be repackaged via QFieldSync? Otherwise the only way I see is to rebuild the whole project from scratch. Or am I missing something?
